# Yii2 add class or function to dropdownlist form field

Tags: javascript, php, css, drop-down-menu, yii2

I need to add a class and a function to a `dropdownlist` in `Yii2 activeform`, here's the code:

```php
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'tipocontratto')->dropDownList(['RES' => 'Residenziale', 'BUS' => 'Business'], ['prompt'=>'Seleziona...'],['maxlenght'=> true]); ?>
```

I need to specify a class for the field and also a JavaScript function.

In normal `textfield` I use this way:

```php
<?= $form->field($model, 'cogn_ragsoc')->textInput(['maxlength' => true,'class'=>'form-control formtesto','onfocus'=>'test()']) ?>
```

and it works perfectly, but in `dropdownlist` it doesn't.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works perfectly.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'tipocontratto')->dropDownList(['RES' => 'Residenziale', 'BUS' => 'Business'], ['prompt'=>'Seleziona...','class'=>'yourclass','onchange'=>'function()']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding options with class eg: :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'tipocontratto')->dropDownList(['RES' => 'Residenziale', 'BUS' => 'Business'], 
['prompt'=>'Seleziona...'],['maxlenght'=> true], 
[options=> ['class' => 'yuorClass']]); ?>
```